# Pyspark saving is not working when called from inside a foreach

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am building a pipeline that receives messages from Azure EventHub and save into databricks delta tables.

All my tests with static data went well, see the code below:

```
body = 'A|B|C|D\n"False"|"253435564"|"14"|"2019-06-25 04:56:21.713"\n"True"|"253435564"|"13"|"2019-06-25 04:56:21.713"\n"
tableLocation = "/delta/tables/myTableName"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CSV converter").getOrCreate()    
csvData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(body.split('\n'))

df = spark.read \
.option("header", True) \
.option("delimiter","|") \
.option("quote", "\"") \
.option("nullValue", "\\N") \
.option("inferShema", "true") \
.option("mergeSchema", "true") \
.csv(csvData)

df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(tableLocation)
```

However in my case, each eventhub message is a CSV string, and they may come from many sources. So each message must be processed separatelly, because each message may end up saved in different delta tables.

When I try to execute this same code inside a foreach statement, It doesn't work. There are no errors shown at the logs, and I cant find any table saved.

So maybe I am doing something wrong when calling the foreach. See the code below:

```
def SaveData(row):
   ...
   The same code above

dfEventHubCSV.rdd.foreach(SaveData)
```

I tried to do this on a streaming context, but I sadly went through the same problem.

What is in the foreach that makes it behave different?

Below the full code I am running:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

--row contains the fields Body and SdIds
--Body: CSV string
--SdIds: A string ID 
def SaveData(row):

  --Each row data that is going to be added to different tables
  rowInfo = GetDestinationTableData(row['SdIds']).collect()  
  table = rowInfo[0][4]
  schema = rowInfo[0][3]
  database = rowInfo[0][2]     
  body = row['Body']

  tableLocation = "/delta/" + database + '/' + schema + '/' + table
  checkpointLocation = "/delta/" + database + '/' + schema + "/_checkpoints/" + table

  spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CSV").getOrCreate()    
  csvData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(body.split('\n'))

  df = spark.read \
  .option("header", True) \
  .option("delimiter","|") \
  .option("quote", "\"") \
  .option("nullValue", "\\N") \
  .option("inferShema", "true") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .csv(csvData)

  df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(tableLocation)

dfEventHubCSV.rdd.foreach(SaveData)
```

Comment: Hi Flavio, it would be very helpful if you can post the exact implementation

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis the full code is too large to post here, but I am gonna edit the post and give you all the code of this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the end of all, as always it is something very simple, but I dind't see this anywere.

Basically when you perform a foreach and the dataframe you want to save is built inside the loop. The worker unlike the driver, won't automatically setup the "/dbfs/" path on the saving, so if you don't manually add the "/dbfs/", it will save the data locally in the worker and you will never find the saved data.

That is why my loops weren't working.