# Can't write to Azure Sql DataWarehouse from databricks pyspark workers

Tags: python-3.x, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to simply write data to azure sql DataWarehouse, while using azure blob storage for staging.

There is a very straight forward tutorial at azure databricks documentation [azure/sql-data-warehouse](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html), which works, if you follow it step by step.

However in my scenario, I have to do the writing from a worker that is executing a foreach.

Here some links related to the issue:

[error-using-pyspark-with-wasb-connecting-pyspark-with-azure-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082556/error-using-pyspark-with-wasb-connecting-pyspark-with-azure-blob)

[github.com/Azure/mmlspark/issues/456](https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/issues/456)

[pyspark-java-io-ioexception-no-filesystem-for-scheme-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352813/pyspark-java-io-ioexception-no-filesystem-for-scheme-https)

So, this code below **WORKS**:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()      
  spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net", "myKey")  
  df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)], ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))  

  (df.write 
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") 
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver:...") 
  .option("user", "user@server") 
  .option("password", "pass") 
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") 
  .option("dbTable", "dbo.table_teste") 
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<container>@<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/") 
  .mode("append")
  .save())
```

However it fails when I insert the code above inside a foreach, just like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()          

def iterate(row):
   # The code above

dfIter = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3, 4)], ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
dfIter.rdd.foreach(iterate)
```

Executing it will generate this exception:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.save.
>   : com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWConnectorException: Exception
>   encountered in SQL DW connector code.
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

I have had the same kind of issue when saving on delta tables: [pyspark-saving-is-not-working-when-called-from-inside-a-foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783356/pyspark-saving-is-not-working-when-called-from-inside-a-foreach)

But in that case, I just needed to setup '/dbfs/' at the begining of the delta table location, so the worker would be able to save it in the right place.

**Based on that, I believe something is missing in the worker, and that is why it is not properly executing this saving. Maybe a library that I should setup into spark config.**

I also looked into databricks community: [save-the-results-of-a-query-to-azure-blo](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8620/i-want-to-save-the-results-of-a-query-to-azure-blo.html) and they managed to solve the issue by setting this config:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
```

PySpark:

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.wasbs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
```

But it didn't work and I got this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem not found

**org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.0 is installed.**

Well, any help?

Comment: Pretty sure you also need the azure-storage jars

Comment: I also thought it for a while. I tried adding it to the spark session from inside the worker, like that: ...config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:5.2.0')... Databricks 5.4 uses azure-storage 5.2. But it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main issue is that you are trying to write from within a foreach loop, which basically renders any kind of batching/scaling moot - which is what the SQL DW connector is designed for. If you really need to write out from within the loop and the data volume is not too huge you might be able to achieve this using the simple JDBC connector: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

But still note that SQL DW is really optimized for large scale write, not for single row ingestion.

Comment: There is an example of writing to DW within a foreach here: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/structured-streaming/examples.html#write-to-azure-sql-data-warehouse-using-foreachbatch-in-python

Comment: The difference is the streaming context and foreachBatch. In my case, I am iterating over IDs, and each ID will give me the information I need to read the right files and save it to DW.

Comment: yes, the example is also referring to streaming. The foreachBatch has little to do with your foreach as far as I understand it.

Comment: This is weird, I don't really understand why this would work only in a streaming scenario. I will try to do it soon, and then I give the feedback.

Comment: again, the foreachBatch() function is something specific to the stream writer, it's not a loop like your rdd.foreach()